# Letter grade to number grade using switch/if statements?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int, switch-statement

I am tasked with creating a java program where the user inputs a grade (D- through A+) and gets a score (0.7 through 4.3)

- If the user inputs "A", they get 4...."B" = 3...."C" = 2...."D" = 1.
- If the user inputs a "+" or a "-" after a letter, the final score is incremented or decremented by 0.3
- So, for example, if the user inputs "C+", they get back a score of "2.3"

So far it works ONLY if the user doesn't add a "+" or "-".

So if the user inputs ONLY a letter, it works.

For some odd reason, if the user inputs a "+" or a "-" after a letter, the output would be "0.3" or "-0.3" respectfully.

I'm not sure why. My AP Comp Sci teacher and I are stumped.

**Here is a relevant snip of my code**

```
String letterGrade;
double numericGrade;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
public boolean getLetterGrade()
{
    System.out.print("Enter a letter grade: ");
    letterGrade = reader.nextLine();
    return (letterGrade.length() < 3) && (("+".equals(letterGrade.substring(1))) || ("-".equals(letterGrade.substring(1))) || (letterGrade.length() == 1));
}
public double getNumericGrade()
{
    numericGrade = 0.0;
    switch(letterGrade.substring(0).toUpperCase())
    {
        case "A":
            numericGrade += 4.0;
            break;
        case "B":
            numericGrade += 3.0;
            break;
        case "C":
            numericGrade += 2.0;
            break;
        case "D":
            numericGrade += 1.0;
            break;
        case "F":
            numericGrade += 0.0;
            break;
    }
    if ("-".equals(letterGrade.substring(1)))
        numericGrade -= 0.3;
    if ("+".equals(letterGrade.substring(1)))
        numericGrade += 0.3;
    return numericGrade;
}
```

My guess is that `numericGrade` is getting reset to 0 after the switch statement, for no reason apparent to me.

Comment: Try utilizing the debugging capabilities that your IDE provides you with, and step through to see what `numericGrade` is each step of the way.

Comment: The switch statement never succeeds with a "A+" because substring(0) gets the entire string, not just the first character

Answer (score 1):

`String.substring(int position)` returns the sub-string from position onwards, if you use "1234".substring(1), it will return "234"

In this case you're using `"C+".substring(0)`, which returns C+ and not C, you need either `String.charAt(0)` or `String.substring(0, 1)`

That's all that is needed to fix it for +/-, but do be aware that if the string entered is of length one (just a letter grade, A/B/C/D/F), then your program will crash because your if statements try to access the second character.  You should check the length and return early if the string entered is too short

Comment: Thank you, this seems to fix the problem. It is my understanding that if the `if` statements are called when there is no second character, the if statements would return `-1`? Is this not the case?

Comment: My bad, that's if you use `letterGrade.substring(1, 2)`, just using `letterGrade.substring(1)` does not throw an error.  If the input is the empty string it will cause an error though, and would not be a bad idea to add some form of error handling for it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, A simple grade interpreter. If you want to understand more in to details of such problems , you could check with Interpreter design pattern

```
public class Grades {
private double score = 0;
public double calculate(char c) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    switch(c){
        case 'A':
            score += 4; 
            break;
        case 'B':
            score += 3;
            break;
        case 'C':
            score += 2;
            break;
        case 'D':
            score += 1;
            break;
        case '+':
            score += 0.3;
            break;
        case '-':
            score -= 0.3;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Argument");
    }

    return score;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    Grades grade = new Grades();
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    while(!line.equals("exit")){

        //validate argument here..
        double value;
        for ( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
            value = grade.calculate(line.charAt(i));

        }
        System.out.println("Grade = " + value);
        line = reader.nextLine();
    }
    reader.close();
}
```